# Displaying firestore timestamp gets error when using onSnapshot() on react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a chat app using firestore where I use Flatlist and querying using onSnapshot() to show both sender and receiver realtime

my sample query below is like this:

```
const ChatMessages = useCallback(() => {
 privateMessage
  .doc(chatId)
  .collection('messages')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const messageList = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      messageList.push(doc.data());
    })
    setMessages(messageList);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
 }, [chatId])
```

then in my sample flatlist I have the user display name, message, and the time created that will be displayed on the screen:

```
<FlatList
  data={messages}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
  removeClippedSubviews={false}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (

   <View>

      <Text style={chatstyle.pmdate}>
        {item.createdAt.toDate().toDateString()}
      </Text>

      <Text>
        {item.displayName}
      </Text>

      <Text>
        {item.message}
      </Text>

   </View>
  )}
/>
```

I would like to display the time and date but when using onSnapshot() I get null is not an object (evaluating 'item.createdAt.toDate') error but when I removed {item.createdAt.toDate().toDateString()} everything is ok. I tried the get() query and the timestamp works fine but of course it's not realtime.

What is the right way to display the timestamp using onSnapshot()?

Comment: Can you show how you create a message document?

Comment: i just send message with firebaseMessage.doc(id).set(userMessages).catch(e => {console.log(e))}

Comment: I was using const newDate = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() this one does not work directly when displaying the date using onSnapshot()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the "latency compensation": "Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately. ... When you perform a write, your listeners will be notified with the new data before the data is sent to the backend". See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) on `onSnapshot()`.

Since you use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to set the value of `createdAt` (which is a good approach), the value of `createdAt` **is calculated by the backend** (the `serverTimestamp` sentinel is replaced by a **server-generated timestamp** in the written data).

Therefore, at the moment the snapshot listener is invoked in your front-end following the local write ("Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately"), **this value is not set** (`item.createdAt.toDate()` generates an error).

One solution is to use the `metadata.hasPendingWrites` property that indicates whether the document has local changes that haven't been written to the backend yet.

For example:

```
const ChatMessages = useCallback(() => {
 privateMessage
  .doc(chatId)
  .collection('messages')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const messageList = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      messageList.push(doc.data());
    })
    if (!querySnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {  // <======
       setMessages(messageList);
    }

  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
 }, [chatId])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to React as well, but for those who are looking a quick solution & couldn't figure out a way to do it , here is one :

```
const ChatMessages = useCallback(() => {
 privateMessage
  .doc(chatId)
  .collection('messages')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const messageList = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     if(querySnapshot.createdAt) // Here is the magic Line of Code
      messageList.push(doc.data());
    })
    setMessages(messageList);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
 }, [chatId])
```

Yes that's it. A single if statement which checks for the createdAt attribute in the data & then only pushes the data to your array.

If you are thinking about the drawbacks of this solution, then here is it :

time for the if() to validate is extra in your program.

PS : I tried the current approved solution on my react application, but still the null issue on the timeStamp was happening.

Comment: Thanks for giving me another idea.